# Open folder in graphical file manager

Tags: mac

I used to use nautilus . command to open the graphical folder / file viewer in red hat linux. Now I moved to mac and it seems that there is no nautilus support in it. Is there any equivalent command that I can use. My scenario is like this, I open a Terminal, go to the folder I want let's say /Users/user1/myapps and I do want to use a command that by typing it in Terminal, it bring me the graphical folder / files view where I am.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there's a command for this, just type:

```
open .
```

`open` is the command line equivalent of double clicking a file or directory in the Finder. `open` either starts the standard application associated with the filesystem object provided as argument or, when used with option `-a` , the application specified.

`open` has some other interesting options, see `man open` for more information.

Comment: Indeed, it's exactly like 'gnome-open .' or 'xdg-open .', one or both of which would probably also have worked in any environment in which you were running nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

apart from `open .` you can also install [Macports](https://guide.macports.org/index.html) and get nautilus itself, I find it better/useful than Finder. Building a nautilus from `git clone git://git.gnome.org/nautilus` is also possible but they  [recommend](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Newcomers/BuildGnome?action=show&redirect=GnomeLove%2FBuildGnome) Fedora 25 and Ubuntu 16.10 so macports' `sudo port install nautilus` just might be easier and smart choice :)